# How to capture into file only the last 30 seconds?

Tags: java, video, camera, capture, jmf

Does anyone have any idea how to capture into file only the last 30 seconds from camera?

It's working something like this.
The camera is working non-stop, but when it catches action ( maybe from button ), I should only get the last 30 seconds of movie.